# different page with chat node.js

Tags: node.js, chat

i'm beginning with node.js, in my first example i'm creating a chat. This char have two page, the first (index.jade) the user insert your nickname and second page (chat.jade) the user can chat with other users.

i have two problems.

the first: when user insert your name, the system change the page (chat.jade) and return the your name wrote but the code ( io.sockets.emit('nicknames', nicknames); ) no execute and i think that's because when change of page no load de funcion en el client (socket.on('nicknames',function(data){ .....)  . Why??

second problem:
when a user send a message, the server send a json with user and message but the client get the user null and message correct. why the user is null??

code:

```
index.jade

$('#form-login').submit(function(){
        var nickname = $('#nickname').val();
        if(nickname !== ''){
            socket.emit('login',nickname, function(data){
                if(!data){
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    });

chat.jade
$('#btnSendMessage').on('click',function(){
  var message = $("#message").val();
  if(message != ''){
    socket.emit('sendMessage',message);
    $('#message').val('');
    $('#message').focus();
  }
});

socket.on('nicknames',function(data){
  var $p = $('<p>'+data+'</p>');
  $('.users').append($p);
});

//app.js
var nicknames = [];

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.on('login', function(data, callback){
        if (nicknames.indexOf(data) != -1){
            callback(false);
        }else{
            callback(true);
            nicknames.push(data);
            socket.set('nickname', data);
                        io.sockets.emit('nicknames', nicknames);
        }
    });

    socket.on('sendMessage', function(data){
        socket.get('nickname', function(err, name){
            console.log('nickname: '+name);
        });

        var message = { "nickname":socket.nickname, "data":data };
        io.sockets.emit('userMessage', message);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Submitting the form navigates away from this page, thus closing a socket connection to the server.
2. Because of the above when client arrives at your `chat.jade`, it establishes new socket connection, which doesn't have `socket.nickname` set - and also you should be using `socket.get('nickname')` - which is an asynchronous functions.

have a look at [my implementation of chat](https://github.com/venil7/chatsecure) using socket.io and agular

Use sessions to tie socket connection to a user session, [link](http://howtonode.org/socket-io-auth)

Use [AngularJs](http://angularjs.org/) or similar frameworks to build Single Page App, to prevent refreshing, and loosing connection

Comment: I understand. is there any way to keep the same socket in different pages??

Comment: @AgustinCastro, one way is to build a Single Page App, like in the example I gave you, whereby navigating between views doesnt actually refresh the page, thus keeping the socket connection. Another way is to use session, and keep all data in session - and use socket just as a transport means between client and server.

Comment: I'm goin to try both methods. 1. if I want to change the view without refreshing the page, using ajax??
2. can you give me a page that explains how to use sessions with socket??